# Correct glass shader

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, glass

i am trying to make a glass shader for a photorealistic scene that im making but i have an issue with a glass of water. My glass in real life has some edge loops in the inner part of it. I modelled them and made a glass shader.
But the inner part of it isnt refracting.[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the best that i could make. But the top part is so bad.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem could be that you are using the light path node at the end, try this, I hope it helps.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Francisco, I am amazed at the glass you were able to acheive!! I have had the most difficult time getting glass to look proper in 2.8. Would you be willing to share your file itself? I followed your suggestions above, but couldn't achieve the results you have.

Comment: @Swirlyking thanks for your comment, here is the link to the file, please let me know if I can help in anything else. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6075" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6075/)

Answer (score 0):

It's best if you share the reference image so we can have proper idea.

1. As for your problem, I think it's because of the inner mesh intersecting the outer mesh, try to scale the inner mesh *inwards*.
2. If it's not a separate mesh then I think you need to adjust your normals.

   - go to edit mode
   - select the whole mesh
   - ctrl + N or go to toolbar -> shading -> under normals: recalculate.
3. If there's a liquid inside then be sure to check [this article out](http://blog.gregzaal.com/2013/10/19/fluid-in-a-glass/) and apply the first method

Comment: Nop, doesn´t work